# what is the meaning of +!! in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I came across this line of code recently, and want to understand what it means and does, as my javascript-foo is not that hot :

```
if ((+!!config.template) + (+!!config.templateUrl) !== 1) {}
```

from what I can gather, it is checking to see if either option is set (so either template, or templateUrl must be set, not both or none)

so, if config.template was set,

- +config.template would not work (template is not a number)
- !config.template would return false (-1)
- !!config.template would return true (0)
- +!!config.template would therefore return 1

if config.template was not set,

- !config.template would return true (0)
- !!config.template would return false (-1)
- +!!config.template would therefore return 0

if then you were to apply the same to config.templateUrl , you would end up with 1 if set, 0 if not

So the final test is to see if the sum of config.template and config.templateUrl is 1 (ie one or the other is set)

Is this valid reasoning ?

Comment: Wow... this had me cry out in pain.

Comment: Almost right, except that `+(true) === 1` and `+(false) === 0`

Comment: Actually the above expression is the equivalent to `if (!config.template === !config.templateUrl) {}`. It looks much simpler that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bool value is being cast to a `Number` by prepending it with +.

`!!` in the code above is checking for existence of the property `template` on `config`. If there is no template found `!!` would usually return `false`, however by prepending `+`, it returns `0`. Both `+!!` statements return numbers, which when they're added together will either be 0 or 1.

The final check will return true if both or none were set / true (`!== 1`)

Comment: @RoryGilchrist : why would the code fail if both were set ? Yes, the expression would be 2, but the test checks for !== 1 , therefore it would execute the code in {} (which was the intention of the author - a message saying "you must specify one or the other)

or am I being thick ?

Comment: You're right, I misread. So basically in the code above, it's want's either none or both to be set, but not just one.

Comment: @RoryGilchrist exactly so: "which when they're added together will be 0, 1 or 2".

Comment: @Armfoot Other way round amigo, it would be false if it were 1, but not 2. `1 !== 1` is fasle because 1 == 1, but `2 !== 1` is true because 2 is not 1.

Comment: @RoryGilchrist yeah xD nevermind, I edited that... I was thinking `===` from the question's comment.